# How may I mount an external drive in fstab and give owbership to multiple users?

Tags: linux, debian, mount, fstab, chown

I mount an external drive on my Raspberry-Pi (Debian/stretch) and I mount my external drive in the `fstab` like this:

```
UUID=1AD09862DC893951 /media/USBHDD1 ntfs-3g nofail,uid=pi,gid=pi,umask=007 0 0
```

Once the disk is mounted, I want to provide ownership (`chown`) for different folders in it to different users.

Currently `sudo chowm -R www-data:www-data /media/USBHDD1/Pi/Data` does not have any impact.

Is this possible? If so what changes do I need to do?

**UPDATE:**

What I am trying to do? I'm installing OwnCloud and wanted to keep OwnCloud data on this drive. This drive is also mounted as a Samba share. Now, for OwnCloud, I needed access (Ownership/Read-Write) on a folder on the Drive. OwnCloud writes to it as www-data

Comment: Could you add a mini directory tree and explain which user will have access to each folder? Are you wanting to set this on boot? If you set it once it should keep it.

Comment: the current command that you are executing will give www-data read-write-exec both for owner and group and for other it gives read if you run `ls -l  | grep Data` (run on parent of Data folder) you can see for yourself. If this is not what you want you need to look into the `chmod` command and you can modify the permissions for owner/group and other. With that you can grant/deny complete access to a folder for users.

Answer (score 4):

While NTFS supports permissions, the mapping from Windows-style to POSIX-style is troublesome and disabled by default in ntfs-3g.

To activate it you should:

- If the disk is shared with Windows – create a UserMapping file which maps Windows SIDs to Linux UIDs, by default ntfs-3g will look for it at:

  ```
  /media/USBHDD1/.NTFS-3G/UserMapping
  ```

  `ntfs-3g.usermap` can semi-automatically generate the list.
- Otherwise you can just add the `permissions` mount option, or manually pick any SID prefix.

http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/#6